# How to mirror Wikipedia pages with wget linux command?

Tags: linux, web, command-line, wget, mirror

I want to mirror Wikipedia pages with wget  Linux command 
I used this command

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./folder-mirror /https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents/A–Z_index
```

but i only get this file 
robots.txt

Comment: Wikipedia don't like that sort of action. Instead, they provide various sorts of dumps. See [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) .

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using wget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Robot exclusion is on by default](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html) in `wget` to keep folks from being jerks and recursively gobbling up someone else's web page and their bandwidth with it.

You can turn it off in your `.wgetrc` file, or you use wget's `-e` switch like: `-e robots=off`

This isn't to say that Wikipedia doesn't have further safe guards in place to insure that your wget doesn't recursively download everything, but it will keep wget from honoring robots.txt and meta.

If you still hit the wall, then perhaps tinkering with the user-agent or something along those lines.

Comment: I hope Wikipedia can avoid recursive gobblement.

Comment: OP's going to put it to the test. I wonder how big of a hard drive you need for everything in wikipedia...

Comment: @JNevill If you try downloading everything (including page history, which wget will run into!) as fully rendered HTML pages, easily tens of terabytes. Possibly hundreds or more.

Comment: I don't doubt it. I was kind of hoping that OP would try it and report back. I have a suspicion that perhaps OP is just trying to download that one page and maybe any css or script that it links to. Like this page, and one non-html child deep.

Answer (score 9):

Don't do that. It places a huge load on the Wikipedia web servers, and your IP will be blocked.

If you want a mirror of Wikipedia, download a dump of their database from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/. The most recent complete dump of the English wiki, as of right now, is available at:

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20160407/

If you only need data from specific pages, consider using [the MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/).

Comment: And... why bother hosting pages from Wikipedia.  Your pages would not be as current as the real thing.

Comment: @Yetti99 Depends what you're trying to do. There's a lot of interesting analysis that you'd need direct access to the data to perform.

Comment: i just want to know how to do it but i will not do

Answer (score 0):

Well, the folks here have been semi-helpful in mentioning how to deal with robots.txt.  You will also need to set your user agent appropriately. There seems to be a formal way to do that to let Wikimedia know who you are by using the use-agent string, and that will prevent you from getting blacklisted for pulling too much at once.  As they mentioned - swamping the servers with requests is not good for anybody, and can lead to your IP being banned.

My use case may be different from yours: I'm just trying to grab single .html files
So far I have  this, which emulates the most recent Firefox:

```
wget -e robots=off --span-hosts --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Stackexchange_and_Reddit
```

But unfortunately this is the output:

> --2022-04-10 04:09:15--  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Stackexchange_and_Reddit
> Resolving en.wikipedia.org (en.wikipedia.org)... 2620:0:863:ed1a::1, 198.35.26.96
> Connecting to en.wikipedia.org (en.wikipedia.org)|2620:0:863:ed1a::1|:443... failed: Permission denied.
> Connecting to en.wikipedia.org (en.wikipedia.org)|198.35.26.96|:443... failed: Permission denied.
> Retrying.

Its another step in the right direction, at least.  I should mention that there seems to be some sort of taboo surrounding the topic of uset-agent "catfishing".  None of the sites I've explore provide the required information in a sort of pre-packaged fashion. I 'm guess that is because they could get a takedown notice or some such.  I'll give this another try soon and edit my response if I get close to the goal.